# default Filtering Sonata admin list without a Filter filed

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using `Sonata MongoDb Admin Bundle` and I need to filter by default my List data without filter `field`.

I have a 'tenant_id' attribute in my model and I want to show models only if the `tenant_id` equal to the `id` of the connected user.

Any one can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override createQuery function of Admin class as described here, https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->field('tenant_id')->equals("YOUR USER ID");
    return $query;
}
```